# Porting app from tomcat to glassfish

Tags: java, tomcat, glassfish

My app have this architecture:

- **struts**
- **spring**
- **dwr**
- **hibernate**

Now we use apache **tomcat 5.5.28**. We wanna switch **to** **Glassfish** for performance.

My question are:

- anyone know if there are problem for porting using this 4 framework?
- anyone know a guide for porting? or ... there are an official guide for porting from tomcat to glassfish?

Comment: Performance is unlikely to be affected by the change.  If there's a problem, it's likely to be your app, not the app server.

Answer (score 7):

> Now we use apache tomcat 5.5.28. We wanna switch to Glassfish for performance.

Don't misinterpret me, I really like GlassFish but... while Grizzly seems to behave very well (see [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/jfarcand/archive/2006/03/can_a_grizzly_r.html), [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/sdo/archive/2007/05/how_to_test_con.html) or [here](http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?messageID=276346)), are you really sure you'll get that better performances? Most of time, performance problems are in the applications and changing the application server won't magically solve them.

> Anyone know if there are problem for porting using this 4 framework?

I didn't experiment this myself but well, porting J2EE stuff shouldn't be a problem unless you are doing non standard things.

> Anyone know a guide for porting? or ... there are an official guide for porting from tomcat to glassfish?

Because you are asking for, have a look at the [Migrate2Glassfish](https://migrate2glassfish.dev.java.net/) page, they have a migration guide (couldn't access it tonight so I can't say anything about it). But, creating the resources your application requires (e.g. DataSource) and deploying the war shouldn't be that complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy the app (WAR / EAR) on glassfish. You're done. 
There shoudln't be a need to modify something.

Which container specific things are you using? JNDI Connections...?
You have to redefine this settings in glassfish. Read the documentation, this should be easy to solve.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on if you use anything specific to tomcat ie loggers or data sources etc... If no then it's really easy. If yes you'll have to replace those usages with generic libraries or their glassfish equivilant.